# Magento 2.3.4 paypal in-context is not working?

Tags: onepage-checkout, payment-methods, paypal, magento2.3.4, popup

Website redirecting to paypal, but I want show paypal popup without redirection to paypal.

I want to enable paypal popup on checkout page during order placed.

I have enabled In-Context Checkout Experience in the configuration but it is not working.

I am using Sandbox Mode to testing this.

How can I do this?